# How to perform XSLT transformation in Chrome using variables

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

I am trying to do an XSL transformation.

However, whenever the variable with a document fragment is referenced, the transformation seems to fail.

I created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/29pwf84c/3/) to demonstrate the issue. The XML in the example is a dummy document to allow the XSLT to run.

What am I doing wrong?

Javascript:

```
var xml = [
    '<p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">',
    '<\/p>'
    ].join('\n');

var xsl = [
    '<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">',
    '<xsl:variable name="xmlVar">',
    '<aaaa value="It works"\/>',
    '<\/xsl:variable>',
    '<xsl:template match="\/">',
    '<ROOT>',
    //works ok after commenting out
    '<xsl:value-of select="$xmlVar\/aaaa\/@value"\/>',
    '<\/ROOT>',
    '<\/xsl:template>',
    '<\/xsl:stylesheet>'
    ].join('\n');



var domParser = new DOMParser();

var xmlDoc = domParser.parseFromString(xml, 'application/xml');

var xslDoc = domParser.parseFromString(xsl, 'application/xml');

var xsltProc = new XSLTProcessor();
xsltProc.importStylesheet(xslDoc);
try{
var result = xsltProc.transformToFragment(xmlDoc, document);
} catch(exc) {
document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = exc;
}

function encodeStr(rawStr) { return rawStr.replace(/[\u00A0-\u9999<>\&]/gim,   
    function(i){
    return '&#'+i.charCodeAt(0)+';'
  });
}

document.getElementById('xslText').innerHTML = encodeStr(xsl);
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = encodeStr((new XMLSerializer).serializeToString(result));
```

HTML:

```
<pre id='xslText'>

</pre>

<pre id='result'>

</pre>

<pre id='error'>

</pre>
```

Comment: btw, firefox is throwing "no data" exception. Chrome is silent. If that helps anyhow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XSLT 1.0 you need to use an extension function like `exsl:node-set` (http://exslt.org/exsl/functions/node-set/index.html) to convert a variable value of type result tree fragment (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#section-Result-Tree-Fragments) to a node-set to be able to use XPath on the nodes e.g.

```js
var xml = [
    '<p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">',
    '<\/p>'
    ].join('\n');

var xsl = [
    '<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="exsl msxml">',
    '<xsl:variable name="xmlVar">',
    '<aaaa value="It works"/>',
    '<\/xsl:variable>',
    '<xsl:template match="/">',
    '<div>',
    '<xsl:choose><xsl:when test="function-available(\'exsl:node-set\')"><xsl:value-of select="exsl:node-set($xmlVar)/aaaa/@value"/><\/xsl:when><xsl:when test="function-available(\'msxml:node-set\')"><xsl:value-of select="msxml:node-set($xmlVar)/aaaa/@value"/><\/xsl:when><\/xsl:choose>',
    '<\/div>',
    '<\/xsl:template>',
    '<\/xsl:stylesheet>'
    ].join('\n');



var domParser = new DOMParser();

var xmlDoc = domParser.parseFromString(xml, 'application/xml');

var xslDoc = domParser.parseFromString(xsl, 'application/xml');

var xsltProc = new XSLTProcessor();
xsltProc.importStylesheet(xslDoc);
try{
var result = xsltProc.transformToFragment(xmlDoc, document);
document.getElementById('result').appendChild(result);
} catch(exc) {
document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = exc;
}
```

```html
<pre id='xslText'>

</pre>

<pre id='result'>

</pre>

<pre id='error'>

</pre>
```

Drawback in terms of cross-browser compatibility with client-side XSLT 1 is that Microsoft use MSXML 3 or 6 in IE and Edge to provide XSLT support and unfortunately MSXML has its own proprietary namespace for such an extension function instead of supporting EXSLT.

Fiddle updated to http://jsfiddle.net/29pwf84c/14/.

Comment: That looks nice, many thanks. I am thinking how to work around the poor cross-browser support, testing this now.

Comment: Martin, I will try to manipulate the XSL to achieve cross-browser support for my case. In case it will not work I will just create 2 sets of templates, one for IE and one for other browsers.....as usual. Although in this case, it does not look like IE fault. many thanks for your help!

Comment: more kudos for the cross-browser support!